# Why am I getting a "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when using the F.write()?

Tags: python

I received a JSON file from an API. I am going to write it to a file in a custom format. My script is:

```
import logging,json,urllib,time
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
logging.info("程序开始执行,%s",log_time)
logging.info("从远程API下载json,http://172.100.0.21:8080/patch/file/filelist",log_time)
url = "http://172.100.0.21:8080/patch/file/filelist?date=2017-08-10"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())['data']
logging.info("测试下载结果,%s",log_time)
with open("packet.sql","w") as F:
    for i in data:
        print("%s %s %s %s" %(type(str(i['time'])),type(str(i['patch_id'])),type(str(i['filename'])),type(str(i['server_ip']))))
        F.write("%s %s %s %s\n" %(str(i['time']),str(i['patch_id']),str(i['filename']),str(i['server_ip'])))
```

But when I attempt to run the script, I'm getting a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 784, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 662, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 444, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 314, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I already translated it to the format to string, so why am I getting:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

when I delete the F.write

```
F.write("%s %s %s %s\n" %(str(i['time']),str(i['patch_id']),str(i['filename']),str(i['server_ip'])))
```

It's correct

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line:

`logging.info("从远程API下载json,http://172.100.0.21:8080/patch/file/filelist",log_time)`

There isn't a `%s` in the format string for the `log_time` to be substituted in to. Remove the second argument and change the line to:

`logging.info("从远程API下载json,http://172.100.0.21:8080/patch/file/filelist")`

And the file runs correctly. Or, add a specifier (like `%s`) in the formatting string.